# Inserting rows into different tables using forein key in SQLite3

Tags: sqlite, triggers, sql-insert

I'm making a sqlite3 database for my bank management program. To create tables I used the following script.

```
  1 CREATE TABLE account_profile(
  2     account_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  3     first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  4     last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  5     date_of_birth TEXT NOT NULL,
  6     phone TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  7     email TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
  8 );
  9 
 10 CREATE TABLE balance(
 11     account_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 12     balance REAL DEFAULT 0,
 13     FOREIGN KEY (account_id)
 14         REFERENCES account_profile (account_id)
 15         ON UPDATE CASCADE
 16         ON DELETE CASCADE
 17 );
```

Now by using an insert command like below

```
INSERT INTO account_profile(first_name, last_name, something...) values (something...);
```

I want that a row is created in the balance table with the account_id 1.

Is it possible? If so, how should I modify the first codes block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an [`AFTER INSERT trigger`](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html):

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_balance AFTER INSERT ON account_profile
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO balance(account_id) VALUES (NEW.account_id);
END;
```

But, since there is a `1:1` relationship between the 2 tables and the only column in the table `balance`, except the foreign key, is `balance`, why do you need another table?
You can have the column `balance` inside `account_profile`:

```
CREATE TABLE account_profile(
     account_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
     last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
     date_of_birth TEXT NOT NULL,
     phone TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
     email TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
     balance REAL DEFAULT 0
);
```

and there is no need to create a trigger and you avoid the overhead of cascaded updates, cascaded deletes and calls to a trigger.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This solution worked well. Your suggestion is valid, but I wanted to know if such a triggering is possible and how to do that.